# Login via curl fails inside bash script, same curl succeeds on command line

Tags: bash, curl

I'm running this login via curl in my bash script. I want to make sure I can login before executing the rest of the script, where I actually log in and store the cookie in a cookie jar and then execute another curl in the API thousands of times. I don't want to run all that if I've failed to login.

Problem is, the basic login returns 401 when it runs inside the script. But when I run the exact same curl command on the command line, it returns 200!

```
basic_login_curl="curl -w %{http_code} -s -o /dev/null -X POST -d \"username=$username&password=$password\" $endpoint/login"
echo $basic_login_curl
outcome=`$basic_login_curl`
echo $outcome
if [ "$outcome" == "401" ]; then
    echo "Failed login. Please try again."; exit 1;
fi
```

This outputs:

```
curl -w %{http_code} -s -o /dev/null -X POST -d "username=bdunn&password=xxxxxx" http://stage.mysite.it:9301/login
401
Failed login. Please try again.
```

Copied the output and ran it on the cmd line:

```
$ curl -w %{http_code} -s -o /dev/null -X POST -d "username=bdunn&password=xxxxxx" http://stage.mysite.it:9301/login
200$
```

Any ideas? LMK if there's more from the code you need to see.

ETA: Please note: The issue's not that it doesn't match 401, it's that running the same curl login command inside the script fails to authenticate, whereas it succeeds when I run it on the actual CL.

Comment: BTW, the string equality operator is `=`, not `==` (the latter is a misguided attempt to ease the programmer by issuing less error messages about invalid operators).

Comment: @Jens: At what point would using `==` actually fail while comparing two strings? just curious really... thanks

Comment: @l'L'l It's really only for POSIX compatibility, I think. On my system, *all* of the Bash built-in `[[`, `[` and `test` as well as `/usr/bin/test` and `/usr/bin/[` do *not* complain about `==`, even with Bash in `--posix` mode. Dash, however, complains about `[ blah == blah ]` ("unexpected operator").

Comment: @l'L'l It suffers from the *all-the-worlds-a-bash* (or Linux) syndrome and fails, e.g. on FreeBSD and Solaris and SunOS; probably other systems and shells as well. There's no valid reason to prefer `==`, unless you deem gratuitious future breakage a feature.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the issues reside in how you are quoting/not quoting variables and the subshell execution. Setting up your command like the following is what I would recommend:

```
basic_login_curl=$(curl -w "%{http_code}" -s -o /dev/null -X POST -d "username=$username&password=$password" "$endpoint/login")
```

The rest basically involves quoting everything properly:

```
basic_login_curl=$(curl -w "%{http_code}" -s -o /dev/null -X POST -d "username=$username&password=$password" "$endpoint/login")
# echo "$basic_login_curl" # not needed since what follows repeats it.
outcome="$basic_login_curl"
echo "$outcome"
if [ "$outcome" = "401" ]; then
    echo "Failed login. Please try again."; exit 1;
fi
```

Running the script through [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net) can be helpful in resolving issues like this as well.

Comment: The issue's not that it doesn't match "401", it's that running the same curl login command inside the script fails to authenticate, whereas it succeeds when I run it on the actual CL. Therefore not selecting this as the best answer

Comment: I get the same result within the script or on the command line, so it's obviously something that's manifested itself within your environment.  I can't tell you why you see different results, but it has nothing to do with my answer, therefore down voting your question due to lack of clarity.

Comment: Also note, the curl command url syntax you are using in your edit is not the same one that was originally posted (in the script). You should try changing it to `$(curl -w "%{http_code}" -s -o /dev/null --data "username=$username&password=$password" -H 'Host: stage.mysite.it' 'http://stage.mysite.it:9301/login' -k)` and see if there's any difference.